# KonvaJs: Change points of line when dragged

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

I am using [KonvaJs](http://konvajs.github.io/) in my project. I am creating a polygon using `Konva.Line` by setting `closed:true`. I need to figure out that whether a point is inside the polygon or not. I am using [Ray-Casting](https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon) algorithm to find point in polygon and it's working fine. But the problem arises when polygon is dragged. When it is dragged the vertices(points) still remains the same and because of that I am not able to get the new coordinates. How can I change the points of polygon so that I can use them? Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nx70pAqMIA7rrovVZuKr?p=preview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While dragging Konva will change `{x,y}` properties of Node (Circle, Rect, Line, etc). All you need is to add `x` and `y` to `points`:

```
vs.push({
  x: points[i] + poly.x(),
  y: points[i + 1] + poly.y()
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P6xTokR4bR8o1D180k40?p=preview

Comment: You nailed it brother. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Hi Lavrton, When shape is added to a group and I drag the group then adding coordinate approach does not work properly. Let's say I have a circle in group. When the group is dragged I need to get the updated the position of circle. By adding the x,y to the position of circle is not updating the coordinates correctly. I mean it's taking the circle to different position :( In this case what should I do? I have created the plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/V7RWHYZUH8wndDhDioXH?p=preview

Comment: @HiteshKumar, why to just add them to one draggable group?

Comment: I need to create polygon which should have behavior similar to the google map poylgon something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/6uusoIsdP3oqzRwiQiEl?p=preview I need not to implement the mid point part of the polygon.